# Dividing relations to achieve BCNF

Tags: database, database-normalization

Is the relation from below correctly divided into relations in BCNF:
R(**a,b**,c,d,e) - a and b are primary keys and there are dependencies such as:

a → c
a → e
c → e

I split the above relations into:

AC(**a**,c)
CE(**c**,e)
AB(**a,b**,d)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about that primary key?  Normally, determining all the candidate keys is part of these kinds of exercises.

An informal way of expressing what we know about candidate keys is that every attribute that's not on the right-hand side (RHS) of any functional dependency must be part of *every* candidate key.

Since I don't know how you determined that {ab} is a candidate key, I'd be inclined to say that, because {abd} is not on any RHS, {abd} must be part of every candidate key.

In short, your FDs say that {abd} is the primary key, not {ab}.

In order for your key and your decomposition to be right, you need to have the additional FD ab->d.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the case that **a** is a primary key and **b** is a primary key, or is it the case that **{a,b}** is the (composite) primary key?  If the columns are separately primary keys, then you have a number of additional but not explicitly stated functional dependencies: **a → bd** and **b → acde**.  If the columns **{a,b}** are a composite PK, then you have an additional functional dependency **ab → cde**.  Either way, the AC and CE relations are fine, and the ABD relation is the other necessary one.  The only issue is 'what are the candidate keys of ABD'?  And the answer is 'either **{a,b}** as a composite PK, or **a** and **b** as two separate candidate keys'.